# Unable to get the paste property of the worksheet class

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, excel-2016

I have the below script that will split and save an excel file based on the values of the first column via a PowerShell script. Here is how the excel file is built up (app 700k-1M rows depending on which file, as there are multiple files I need to split)

```
´´´    Column1 #  Column2  #  Column3   ´´´
´´´ AA # data  #  data     #  data      ´´´
´´´ AA # data  #  data     #  data      ´´´
´´´ AB # data  #  data     #  data      ´´´
´´´ AC # data  #  data     #  data      ´´´
´´´ AC # data  #  data     #  data      ´´´
```

The result should be multiple files with filenames AA.xlxs, AB.xlxs, AC.xlxs and of course the according rows data.

The script is working but a small issue I am having is out of about 4000 files, a handful of them contain no data.

I receive an error when this occurs;

```
    Unable to get the Paste property of the Worksheet class
At line:43 char:5
+   $wksheet.Paste($wksheet.Range("A1"))
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    +   CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    +   FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

The file is still created with the correct naming convention and saves fine but it is missing the data related to the unique value. This does not happen each time I run the script either. Sometimes it will not throw an error, sometimes it could be 1 file or it could be 3 or 4. It's never the same file name either.

Is there any reason as to why this occurs and how do I go about fixing it?

My script is below;

```
Function Create-Excel-Spreadsheet {
Param($NameOfSpreadsheet)

# open excel
$objexcelnew = New-Object -ComObject Excel.application
$objexcelnew.visible = $false


# add a worksheet
$workbook = $objexcelnew.Workbooks.Add()
$xl_wksht= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$xl_wksht.Name = $NameOfSpreadsheet

return $workbook
}

$objexcelexis = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb = $objexcelexis.WorkBooks.Open(($path = "C:\Users\Desktop\test.xlsx")) # Change the path for the location of the excel file.

$objexcelexis.Visible = $false
$objexcelexis.DisplayAlerts = $false
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)

$usedRange = $ws.UsedRange
$usedRange.AutoFilter()

$totalRows = $usedRange.Rows.Count


$rangeForUnique = $usedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize($UsedRange.Rows.Count-1) 
[string[]]$UniqueListOfRowValues = $rangeForUnique.Columns.Item(1).Value2 | sort -Unique

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $UniqueListOfRowValues.Count; $i++) {
    $newRange = $usedRange.AutoFilter(1, $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i])

    $workbook = Create-Excel-Spreadsheet $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i]
    $wksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

    $range = $ws.UsedRange.Cells
    $range.Copy()

    $wksheet.Paste($wksheet.Range("A1"))
    $xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
    $workbook.Activesheet.Cells.EntireColumn.Autofit();
    $wksheet = $Workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
    $wksheet.PageSetup.Orientation = 2
    $workbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\Desktop\" + $UniqueListOfRowValues[$i], $xlFixedFormat) # Change the save path for the xlsx files
    $workbook.Close($false)

    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($rangeForUnique.Columns.Item(1))
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ws.UsedRange.Cells)
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($range)
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wksheet)
    [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objexcelexis)
    [System.GC]::Collect()

   }
```

Comment: Could be that you are releasing $objexcelexis in the loop and $ws relies on it in the next loop.

Comment: Even without the release $objexcelexis in the loop I still receive the error.